# Format time from military to regular in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert times that come from that database in the form `10:00, 23:00, 1:00, 9:00` etc.

I have two strings:

```
   NSString *timeFrom = @"10:00";
   NSString *timeTo = @"18:00";
```

I wish to display them in the app with the format: `10:00AM - 6:00PM`.
I am using NSDateFormatter for this but am not getting the correct results.

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
   NSDate *timeFromDateWithFormatter = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeFrom];
   NSDate *timeToDateWithFormatter = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeTo];
```

I am looking for a feature within NSDateFormatter that will do the conversions to "standard" time and add the AM/PM accordingly.  However, this code results in `timeFromDateWithFormatter` having the value `2000-01-01 15:00:00 +0000` and `timeToDateWithFormatter` being nil after this code is run.

Comment: FYI - `23:00` and `9:00`, etc. are not military format. They are simply 24-hour time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert from `H:mm` to `h:mma`. To do so, you need two date formats.

```
NSDateFormat *oldFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
oldFormatter.dateFormat = @"H:mm"; // The old format
NSDateFormat *newFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
newFormatter.dateFormat = @"h:mma"; // The new format

NSString *timeFrom = @"10:00";
NSString *timeTo = @"18:00";

NSDate *dateFrom = [oldFormatter dateFromString:timeFrom];
NSString *newTimeFrom = [newFormatter stringFromDate:dateFrom];

NSDate *dateTo = [oldFormatter dateFromString:timeTo];
NSString *newTimeTo = [newFormatter stringFromDate:dateTo];

NSLog(@"old times: %@ - %@", timeFrom, timeTo):
NSLog(@"new times: %@ - %@", newTimeFrom, newTimeTo):
```

This will give the output:

> old times: 10:00 - 18:00
>     new times: 10:00am - 6:00pm